# How can I split an array in MIPS?

Tags: mips, mips32, mips64

In order to display an image in the BitMap display of MARS I am trying to loop through an array of Hex values placed in a txt file. The values in the txt file are in the following manner:

0x40E6, 0x40E6, 0x40E6, 0x40E6, 0x40E6, 0x40E6, 0x40E6, 0x40E6,...

How can I loop through it and take each Hex value separately to use it and color the BitMap display?

This is what I have done so far. It reads the whole file and prints the content.

```
# Getting File
        li $v0, 13
        la $a0, bgFile
        li $a1, 0
        syscall
        move $s0, $v0
    ####################################################
    # Read File
        li $v0, 14
        move $a0, $s0
        la $a1, fileWords
        la $a2, 24576
        syscall
    #####################################################   
    # Print File Content
        #li $v0, 4
        #la $a0, fileWords
        #syscall
    #####################################################
    # Close File
        li $v0, 16
        move $a0, $s0
        syscall
    #####################################################
    # Close Program
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Comment: I would check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066572/bitmap-display-on-mars-simulator). It should be able to lead you in the right direction.

Comment: You need to work out an algorithm, and you don't have to think in assembly to work one out.  Once you have that, then just do the same in assembly.

Comment: @ErikEidt Yes, that's what I'm trying to do but I just can't find enough documentation around MIPS. The information I find is always so basic. Do you have any idea if it is possible to retrieve/print a char from a string?

eg. "k" in ErikEidt

I think this would solve my problem.

Comment: Of course it is possible.  If you can do it in C or Java then you can certainly do it in assembly.  If you're asking how to do arraay references in MIPS, that's available information, still pretty basic.  If you want to know how to pur and use an array reference in some context, you're lookung for an algorithm.

Comment: I'm assuming the hex codes are saves as ascii text, rather than actual raw numbers. If it's human-readable in the `.txt` file you're going to need to do some conversions to get it back into the form the bitmap screen can use.